# Проблема с меню "ПУСК" и выходом на рабочий стол

Tags: windows-10

В windows 10 открылось на весь экран меню пуск и не закрывается, при попытке выхода на рабочий стол появляется заставка без папок, ярлыков и файлов. При нажатии на лкм возвращает в "ПУСК", перезагрузка не помогает, так же все папки и файлы показываются только на весь экран и уменьшить его не получается. Если кто сталкивался с таким, скажите что мне делать

Comment: После чего появилась проблема?

Comment: точно не знаю, пришел с работы а тут такое, видимо кто-то из сестер или братьев залез а признаться боится

Comment: Случайно не планшетный режим? https://www.asus.com/ru/support/FAQ/1013056/